# "Helpful Links" should be more visible in Ask Question page, Area 51 Discussions

Tags: feature-request, area-51, hyperlinks

The text color of the links to [How to ask a good question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The help center](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/help) on [Area 51 Discussions Ask Question page](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) are way too dark:

[image]

Dark enough, in fact, to be mistaken for regular text and not a link to a help page.  Upon looking in the CSS, I found that the links are colored with `color: #24304C;`; whereas the help links on (most of, [CodeGolf's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) are green) the other sites' Ask Question pages are colored with `color: #4e82c2;`:

[image]

The latter color makes the links blue, which makes the help link far more obvious than the nearly-black color on Area 51 Discussions' Ask Question help links.

**Feature-request:**  Can we update the color of the help links to be blue, or a color that will stand out more?

---

**EDIT**

This should also apply to those links in the "tagging help" icon:

[image]